# Download pdf directly to browser when generated with itext

Tags: java, spring, pdf-generation, itext

I am using itext to generate a pdf file from an html string. I get this error in my console:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: %PDF-1.4
```

This is the code in my controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/print",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void  print(String html,HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException,DocumentException {
    try{
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
        // step 3
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph(html));
        // step 5
        document.close();

        // setting some response headers
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control",
                "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        // setting the content type
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        // the contentlength
        response.setContentLength(baos.size());
        // write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
        OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
        baos.writeTo(os);
        os.flush();
    }
    catch(DocumentException e) {
        throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: `%PDF-1.4` is the header of a PDF file. Every PDF *must* start with `%PDF-1.` followed by a number from `0` to `7`. Which line in your code is causing the Uncaught Error? At first sight, I don't see anything wrong in your code, but I might be overlooking something. The error message should provide a line number. Please tell us which line corresponds with that line number.

Comment: Note: if `html` is HTML, then `new Paragraph(html)` will show you the HTML. In other words: if you have `<b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i>` then the text on your PDF will be "<b>bold</b> and `<i>italic</i>" NOT "**bold** and *italic*". (But this is so obvious that you probably already knew this.)

Comment: The error is not in server, it appears in the console in my browser. I have generated the file in a temp directory now and it is generated well. The problem is when I read it back to download it in browser. Thats when I get the error.

Comment: Did you try your app on different browsers / different computers? Maybe your browser isn't configured to show PDFs. A browser expects HTML. If it gets a file in another format, it needs a plug-in. E.g. the Adobe Reader plug-in. Some browsers use a different PDF viewer. E.g. Firefox uses pdf,js, Chrome uses Chrome PDF viewer, Safari uses Preview,... If there's nothing to view the PDF on the client side, you won't see any PDF.

Comment: Try adding `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sample.pdf");` What happens if you do that?

Comment: I tried adding the header but it still gives the same error. I also tried in different browsers.

Comment: You say "it appears in the console in my browser" which is strange, because a browser usually doesn't show a console window. Are you sure you're not seeing an HTML page created on the server that shows a status code "500"  and shows the error as being a Tomcat error (or whatever application server you're using). Something in your question isn't right. You are not giving us the information we need to solve the problem.

Comment: The console appears in inspect element in the browser. there is no error in the tomcat error log.

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of "inspect element"? Also "inspect element" is meant to inspect HTML. Surely you don't expect a tool that is meant to inspect HTML to be able to understand PDF. Also: not every browser has this "inspect element" functionality. What happens in the other browsers you've tried? Also: what happens if you try the [Hello World demo](http://demo.itextsupport.com/book/hello.pdf)? That demo uses basically the same code as yours.

Comment: I figured it out. I was making the post to the controller using ajax (stupid me :P). I did a regular post by form and it worked. I also added the @ResponseBody on top of the function in my controller

Comment: Any chance someone could post C# equivalent code? I'm struggling getting it all converted myself.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to stream the PDF file's bytes directly to the output stream and flush the response. In Spring you can do this like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/displayProcessFile/{processInstanceId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> displayProcessFile(@PathVariable String processInstanceId) throws UnauthorizedUserAccessException{
    Document processFile=null;
    try {
        processFile = documentService.retrieveProcessFile(Long.parseLong(processInstanceId));
    } catch (ProcessFileNotFoundExpection e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
    headers.add("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + processFile.getDocName());
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(processFile.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Streaming PDF bytes directly to the browser will fail with some browsers because of the binary nature of PDF. Some browsers need the exact file size of the PDF. To achieve this, many developers create the PDF in memory first (using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`) and then pass the length of the PDF in the HTTP header: `response.setContentLength(baos.size());`. I don't think your answer solved the problem. Although setting the content-disposition to `attachment` (not `inline` as is done in your answer), might do the trick.